# Converting time from a string

Tags: javascript

Using javascript how will I address a scenario wherein I need to convert a time from standard format to military time from a string. For example I have a string like:

```
  Example 1 __ MON-FRI 9:00am - 9:00pm SAT 9:00am - 7:00pm
  Example 2 __ MON-FRI 9:00 am - 9:00 pm SAT 9:00 am - 7:00 pm
  Example 3 __ MON-FRI 9am - 9pm SAT 9am - 7pm
  Example 4 __ MON-FRI 9 am - 9 pm SAT 9 am - 7 pm
```

If I have a string above the expected output would be: 
MON-FRI 9:00 - 21:00 SAT 9:00 - 19:00

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: please paste code in right way int ambigious

Comment: Consider having a look at momentjs.com

Comment: A set of examples doesn't constitute a specification.

Answer (score 0):

You will need any function to convert your time from 12h format to 24h format, like:

```
function convertTo24Hour(time) {
    var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
    if(time.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
        time = time.replace('12', '0');
    }
    if(time.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
        time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
    }
    return time.replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
}
```

And for extracting the time from your strings you can use a regex like:

```
/\d+:\d+am|\d+:\d+pm/g
```

This

```
"MON-FRI 9:00am - 9:00pm SAT 9:00am - 7:00pm".replace(/\d+:\d+am|\d+:\d+pm/g, function (a) { return convertTo24Hour(a); });
```

Will result this

```
MON-FRI 9:00 - 21:00 SAT 9:00 - 19:00
```

EDIT

Fixed the regex pattern to:

```
/\d+:?\d{0,2}\s?am|\d+:?\d{0,2}\s?pm/g
```

And the time format converter function to:

```
function convertTo24Hour(time) {
    var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
    if(time.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
        if(time.indexOf(':' == -1)) {
            time = time.replace('12', '0:00');
        }
        time = time.replace('12', '0');
    }
    if(time.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
        if(time.indexOf(':' == -1)) {
            time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12)+':00');
        }
        time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
    }    
    return time.replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
}
```

Now it should work to all your strings.

Comment: Hi Pablo, Thanks for the response it works on example 1. It's fine that way. How about if my string is "MON-SAT 9 H - 21 H SUN 9 H - 21 H" is it possible to convert this in military format? similar to the expected output that was mentioned? Thank you.